# Gtk Keybinder does not respond

Tags: python, linux, gtk

I'm using a `Keybinder` in a `Gtk+3` application, but it doesn't get any key combinations.
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Keybinder', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Keybinder
from gi.repository import Gtk


def test_func(data):
    print data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wnd = Gtk.Window()
    wnd.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
    wnd.show_all()

    if not Keybinder.bind('<Super>q', test_func, 'Hi there!'):
        print "Keybinder.bind() failed."

    Gtk.main()
```

I expect the program to execute `test_func` when I press `Windows+q` key combo, but it just does nothing.
I'm running it on `Debian Jessie` with `xfce4` if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using the `GIR`-based Python bindings, I'm pretty sure you need to call

```
Keybinder.init()
```

manually before calling any other functions from the Keybinder library.

(From what I can tell, the static `python-keybinder` Python bindings do this for you, but the introspected bindings do not.)