# Gnome Keybinder doesn't bind properly to XF86AudioPlay

Tags: python, gtk, key-bindings, gnome, gdk

I've successfully managed to get a Python program to listen for <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> even when the window doesn't have focus.

However I can't seem to capture `<FX86Audio...>` events even though the succesfully bind (if spelled correctly).

Here is a code snippet that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##!/usr/bin/python3.5       <- Test this every now and then for compatability

# Reqquires:
# sudo apt-get install libkeybinder-3.0-0 gir1.2-keybinder


'''
From : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517261/global-hotkey-in-python3-using-gtk-and-xlib
'''
import gi
# Python 2
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Keybinder', '3.0')
# Python 3
#gi.require_versions({"Gtk": "3.0", "Gdk": "3.0", "Keybinder": "3.0"})
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Keybinder, Pango

class A:
    def __init__(self):

        # Basic setup of a window with a label
        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.lab = Gtk.Label(label="Hello World!")
        self.lab.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription("sans 36"))

        self.win.add(self.lab)
        self.win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.win.show_all()

        self.count = 0

        key = Keybinder  # The module to bind keys
        # key.bind(KEYCOMBINATION, FUNC, ARG)
        key.bind("<control><alt>p", self.say, "Hello")
        key.bind("<control><alt>o", self.say, "World!")
        key.bind("<XF86AudioPlay>", self.say, "World :)")
        key.bind("<XF86AudioPause>", self.say, "World :(")
        key.bind("<AudioPlay>", self.say, "World :/")

        key.init()  # Call the mainloop something like Gtk.main()

    def say(self, key, msg):
        self.count += 1
        print(msg)
        # Python 2
        text="Pressed "+ key + " " + str(self.count) + " times"
        self.lab.set_label(text)
        # Python 3
        # self.lab.set_label(f"Pressed {key} {self.count} times")


A()  # Call the object
if not Keybinder.bind("<control><alt>p", A.say, "Bad News 1"):
    print "Keybinder.bind() failed 1."
if not Keybinder.bind("<XF86AudioPlay>", A.say, "Bad News 2"):
    print "Keybinder.bind() failed 2."
Gtk.main()  # Call the main loop
```

As mentioned earlier these key bindings are accepted but do not work:

```
    key.bind("<XF86AudioPlay>", self.say, "World :)")
    key.bind("<XF86AudioPause>", self.say, "World :(")
    key.bind("<AudioPlay>", self.say, "World :/")
```

The keyboard works for pausing and playing with `rhythembox`.

Thinking that Unity was getting in the way I remapped `<XF86AudioPlay>` keyboard shortcut to another sequence to no avail.

On other websites it talks about `gsettings` and mine seem OK for Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity interface:

[image: gsettings glugins.media-keys.png]

---

## Reply to comments

Here is `xev` output:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x259, subw 0x0, time 802402347, (1900,975), root:(3820,1027),
    state 0x10, keycode 172 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Adding `init` and changing order did not make `XF86AudioPlay` work but on the other hand did not break <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> which continue to work.

Here's what I added / changed order of:

```
    Keybinder.init()
    key = Keybinder  # The module to bind keys
    key.init()  # Call the mainloop something like Gtk.main()
```

---

## Reply to comments 2

Added:

```
if not Keybinder.bind("<control><alt>p", A.say, "Bad News 1"):
    print "Keybinder.bind() failed 1."
if not Keybinder.bind("<XF86AudioPlay>", A.say, "Bad News 2"):
    print "Keybinder.bind() failed 2."
```

The first keybinder is successful but the second one prints to terminal:

```
Keybinder.bind() failed 2.
```

Comment: @stovfl the other bound keys do work. These are not accelerator keys cause they work when widow doesn't have focus.

Comment: @stovfl I tried everything with the exception of accelerator parse which wasn't clear to me. I updated my answer with results (or lack thereof).

Comment: @stovfl Updated with `not Keybinder.bind(...` and the broken shortcut key is generating an error...

Comment: So `.bind("<XF86AudioPlay>", ...` not accepted by `Keyboard.bind` and therefore no callback. I assume it's unknown either by `Keyboard` or `Gtk`. Try `"XF86AudioPlay"` without brackets.

Comment: @stovfl Before posting question I tried leaving off `<>` and it instantly generated an error message on `jey.bind`.

Comment: My own results: `WARNING **: Binding '<control><alt>p' failed!`, this seq are allready used by my Window Manager. `.bind("XF86AudioPause"` returns `True`. Can't verify callback, but with `.bind("XF86MonBrightnessDown",` the callback is working.

Comment: @stovfl You can post an answer if you like. It was indeed the `<>` had to be removed around `XF86AudioPlay` which is also used by Ubuntu Unity DM but doesn't seem to block it to Gnome Gtk. Also I rewrote the `if not Keybinder.bind()`. Now I just have to save mouse position, move to Movie window, send left click, move back to previous window, reactivate and position mouse where it was :) Also stick Gtk.main() within Tkinter's root.mainloop() THANKS for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: 'Keybinder' doesn't bind properly to `'<XF86AudioPlay>'`

1. According to the documentation man have to call `Keyboard.init()` before any other `Keyboard....` function.
2. By eval the return value from the `Keyboard.bind(...` function man can verify if the binding was successfull.

   ```
   keysym = '<XF86AudioPlay>'
   if not Keybinder.bind(keysym, callback):
       print('bind "{}" failed!'.format(keysym))
   ```
3. According to the output of `xev` and `GNOME gettings` the `keysym` have to be `'XF86AudioPlay'` without enclosing brackets.

   ```
   Keybinder.bind('XF86AudioPlay', callback)
   ```

---

**Reference**:

- [gtk-keybinder-does-not-respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146239)
- [Keybinder.init](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Keybinder-3.0/functions.html#Keybinder.init)

  > Initialize the keybinder library.
  >   This function must be called after initializing GTK, before calling any other function in the library. Can only be called once.
- [Keybinder.bind](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Keybinder-3.0/functions.html#Keybinder.bind)

  > Returns:  `True` if the accelerator could be grabbed
  >   Grab a key combination globally and register a callback to be called each time the key combination is pressed.

---

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - gi.__version__: 3.22.0 - keybinder-3.0, 0.3.2-1***